# Confused of "the conference isn't until later today"

Tags: grammar

In this techcrunch [article](https://techcrunch.com/2018/01/09/huaweis-u-s-distribution-plans-are-thwarted-again-as-att-reportedly-backs-out-of-a-deal/), I noticed a rather strange sentence:

> Huawei’s CES press conference isn’t until later today, but the company’s already having a rough time of it.

I can't wrap my head around the "conference isn't until later today" part. Isn't it more common to say "the conference will not begin until later today"?

Answer (score 1):

The present tense simple is often [used for a future event](https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/simple-present-future-events/) when there is a time expression indicating when the event is expected to take place.

> The new, stricter regulations *don't* come into effect for five years, but automakers are already hard at work designing new technologies.

Just as acceptable is the future tense:

> The new, stricter regulations *won't* come into effect for five years, but automakers are already hard at work designing new technologies.

With events in the near future — in your example in a matter of hours — the tendency would be even greater to use the present tense.

> When is the concert?
>
> It starts at 8:00, so we can eat around 7:00 and still make it on time.

Answer (score 0):

"Will not begin" is grammatically correct. The idiomatic "isn't" would be much more common. It is easier to say and others will understand what is meant.